# HTML: Video Background blocks logo

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website and I set a video for the website background.
The problem now is that when I try to insert the logo at the top of the website but the video blocks the image.
[Image of my CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyNds.png)
[Current View of my Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TvjK.jpg)

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; } .video-background{ position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; width : auto; height: auto; z-index: -100; } media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9){ .video-background{ width: 100%; height: auto; } } media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9){ .video-background{ width: auto; height: 100%; } } .navigation{ margin: 10px 50px; height: 60px; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>CSC1026: Tutorial Website</title>

<link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>

 <header>
 
  <video autoplay loop class="video-background" muted plays-inline>
  <source src="Workaholic.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  
  
 <div class= "navigation">
  <img src= "logo.png" class = "logo">
 </div>
  
 </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I added a photo of my css

Comment: Can you add the CSS here?

Comment: *
{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 
}

.video-background{
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 min-width: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 width : auto;
 height: auto;
 z-index: -100;
 
}

 media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9){
 .video-background{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 }
}

 media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9){
 .video-background{
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
 }
}

.navigation{
 margin: 10px 50px;
 height: 60px;
 
}

Comment: Sorry, by here, I mean in your question, instead of an image.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please include all of the code necessary to produce the problem in the question itself. It takes a lot of time to write a question which is easy to answer. Check out [mcve] for more information on what we expect. Thanks!

Comment: My bad, i added it. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

1. `<header>` needs `position: relative` and `background: none`
2. `<video>` and `<img>` need `position: absolute` and `display: block`
3. `<img>` needs `background: none` and `z-index:`(at least 1 greater than `<video>` `z-index` if any).
4. If you think you really need `.navigation` (you probably don't) -- add the same properties of `<img>` to it and adjust accordingly.

```css
main {
  position: relative;
  top: 30vh;
  left: 0;
  width: 99vw;
  height: auto;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  background: none;
  width: 99vw;
  height: auto;
}

img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 15vw;
  height: 30vh;
  background: none;
}

video {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="https://branditprintit.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/logo-degin-logo-design-design-art-free.png">
</header>
<main>
  <video src='https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/005610.mp4' muted plays-inline autoplay loop></video>
</main>
```

Comment: zer00ne thanky you very much it seems it works just one more question if you are available. Now with the changes you recommended basically the video isn't the background of the website and its under the logo. Is there anyway that I could insert the logo in a position above the video?

Comment: I just followed the HTML in which the video is within the header. Move the video out of the header and place it under the header.

Comment: Thanks for the help i might be doing something wrong and I still cant fix it. I cant change the location of the image and the video starts below the image. In my head, I want the video to be the background of the website and the logo to be at the top left corner and not above the video.

Comment: What's up? First you say, *"Is there anyway that I could insert the logo in a position above the video?"* Now you say, *"the logo to be at the top left corner and not above the video.".*